# Daisy UI card border color

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

How do you change the color of a card border using Daisy UI?

I can see that `bordered` adds a black border around my cards. But when I try various tailwind css classes, such as `border-white` the border does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://daisyui.com/components/card), you can see the example using `card-bordered`.  You can add  `border-white` to that.

```
<div class="card card-bordered border-white">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/400/250">
  </figure> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title">Top image
      <div class="badge mx-2 badge-secondary">NEW</div>
    </h2> 
    <p>Rerum reiciendis beatae tenetur excepturi aut pariatur est eos. Sit sit necessitatibus veritatis sed molestiae voluptates incidunt iure sapiente.</p> 
    <div class="justify-end card-actions">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary">More info</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```